# Could anybody tell me why this is happening in Photoshop 2022 character panel when I select the font family all the weights of the font are selected

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]

Please provide me with a solution if someone has about why this is happening in Photoshop 2022.

Comment: You'll need to ask Adobe. This is most likely a localized issue and tech support is off-topic here.